# How to structure class for Couchdb HTTP api?

Tags: c#, rest, f#, couchdb

I was trying Couch DB api. But unable to structure class structure for it. Like for artist if I am using class to post that will be having Name and Album field. But while retrieving it, it will be having _id and _rev field. Now, id can be taken care of by adding one more field to artist class but I needed _rev field to update the document.

Now, how can I do that in statically typed language like C# / F#?

Please let me know if any further information required.

Answer (score 3):

_id is couchdb's way of uniquely identifying a document. You can set it or couchdb will set a uuid when the document is inserted.

_rev is couchdb's way of identifying the revision of a document. Assume you want to add new details to an existing doc, you'll have to tell couchdb which revision you've used to update the document. If some other change has been made to the same document your update will be rejected.

I'd implement this using the decorator pattern:

Your domain model will have an Album Class with everything that's in the Album. Your data access layer can add a decorator that stores the _id and _rev. If you store a document to database, you'll know to generate (or let couchdb generate) a new _id if your object does not implement a couchdb_decorator. If the decorator is implemented you can access the _id and _rev from it. When loading an object from your couch, just set it up so that it is decorated and contains these details.

Comment: I'm not sure which part you need an example for and there are too many elements to cover the whole issue.http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html is a good example about how you should map. If you then use the http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx to add a property for _id and _rev as well as the behaviour to update an object if it's out of date in memory when you want to persist it to couch. Finally you can look at http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/intro/consistency.html#case-study to understand how the _rev is used.

Answer (score 1):

For a similar need ([in Java](https://github.com/Hypertopic/Porphyry/blob/master/src/org/hypertopic/RESTDatabase.java)), I used the "data access object" pattern.

Here is its structure in pseudo-code :

- `Class RESTDatabase`

  - `constructor(baseURL)`
  - `get(id): JSONObject`
  - `put(JSONObject)`
  - `delete(JSONObject)`

Note: `JSONObject` is used in `delete` because you need both `_id` and `_rev`.

On the upper layer, you can define business classes, with some methods that use "reserved" attributes, and others giving access to "free" attributes.

For example :

- `Class Artist`

  - `getName(): string`
  - `getFreeAttributes(): JSONObject`.

Answer (score 0):

To get started rather quickly you might want to have a look at MyCouch - THE async CouchDb for .NET - https://github.com/danielwertheim/mycouch

You have a Getting started article here (about albums and artists): http://danielwertheim.se/get-up-and-running-with-couchdb-and-c-using-mycouch-on-windows/

Look in the Wiki for info on how to get started, but basically:

```
using(var client = new MyCouchClient("http://localhost:5984/mydb")) {
    var putJsonResponse = await client.Documents.PutAsync(...json...);

    var putEntityResponse = await client.Entities.PutAsync(myEntity);
}
```

Where you would just model an entity that fits your domain:

```
public class Artist
{
    public string ArtistId { get; set; }
    public string ArtistRev { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Album[] Albums { get; set; }
}

public class Album
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Tracks { get; set; }
}
```

using a client to store model according to above:

```
var artist = new Artist
{
    ArtistId = "5",
    Name = "Foo bar",
    Albums = new[]
    {
        new Album { Name = "Hello world!", Tracks = 9 }
    }
};

var response = await db.Entities.PutAsync(artist);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried mycouch but facing error while updating entities. :(

Comment: What error? Did you include required rev and id members?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to answer... Was on vacation. Will do it today and file a error on github.